# ODBC call failed - ms access to MySQL query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to convert the below query on msaccess to a SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Main.Reference, Main.Date, Main.Company, Main.Insured, Main.[Third Party], Main.[Claim No], Main.[Date Paid], Main.Invoice, Main.Att, Main.[Reg No], Main.Make, (([Main].[Amount Paid])<[INVOICE]) Or ([Amount Paid] Is Null) AS Expr1, Main.[Amount Paid], Main.[EFT No]
FROM Main
WHERE (((Main.Date)>=[From Date YYYY-MM-DD] And (Main.Date)<=[To Date YYYY-MM-DD]) And ((Main.Company)=upper([Enter Company])) And ((((Main.[Amount Paid])<[INVOICE]) Or ([Amount Paid] Is Null))<>False))
ORDER BY Main.Company;
```

This is a report to show what invoices are outstanding per company. The above statement is on my current ms access query in SQL view. When I open the option "Print invoices outstanding by company" it tells me "odbc call failed".

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the parameters and remove DistinctRow:

```
PARAMETERS [From Date YYYY-MM-DD] DateTime, [To Date YYYY-MM-DD] DateTime;

SELECT Main.Reference, Main.Date, Main.Company, Main.Insured, Main.[Third Party], Main.[Claim No], Main.[Date Paid], Main.Invoice, Main.Att, Main.[Reg No], Main.Make, (([Main].[Amount Paid])<[INVOICE]) Or ([Amount Paid] Is Null) AS Expr1, Main.[Amount Paid], Main.[EFT No]
FROM Main
WHERE (((Main.Date)>=[From Date YYYY-MM-DD] And (Main.Date)<=[To Date YYYY-MM-DD]) And ((Main.Company)=upper([Enter Company])) And ((((Main.[Amount Paid])<[INVOICE]) Or ([Amount Paid] Is Null))<>False))
ORDER BY Main.Company;
```